# How to make Gmail push notifications continuously sync on iPhone 8?

Tags: iphone, mail.app, email, notifications, gmail

My push notifications do not continuously sync with my gmail inbox. On my computer, I delete emails but the notification remains on my phone. Is there a way to have the push notifications continuously sync with what I do in my gmail on another device?

Does the Mail app accomplish this instead of Gmail app?

Comment: Is your  phone connected to wifi and low power mode is off ?

Comment: @anki yes, it is continuously connected and never goes into low power mode